# Regex for \n not surrounded with double quotes

Tags: regex

How do I match all newline chars \n that are not surrounded by " in regex.
For example:

It should match each of these newlines:

```
"2547026616"
79587329
,"A","2547026616
"79587329","
```

But shouldn't match these (except for the last \n):

```
"254702661679587329"
"A"
"254702661679587329"
```

Comment: Which programming language  are you using ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: No particular language just looking for general regex. Sorry, what's not clear? I'm happy to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex might be what you're looking for:

```
(?:(?<!")\n(?!"))|(?:(?<=")\n(?!"))|(?:(?<!")\n(?="))
```

This will catch any newline that is not preceded by a quotation mark and/or not followed by a quotation mark, it uses negative and positive look-ahead and look-behind, you can read about them [more here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Depending on your programming language these might not be supported, and/or you might need to do some escaping in the regex.

Here is an [example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wE8eK8/2), I've used `x\n` but this is just to make it easy to display the matches.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the links as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([^"]\n.?|.?\n[^"])
```

It matches the 2 characters surrounding the \n as well (if present)

If you want also the last line to end with a double quote, even if it is not followed by \n, then extend the regexp to:

```
([^"](\n.?|$)|.?\n[^"])
```

... and if the first line must start with a double quote, then extend to:

```
([^"](\n.?|$)|(^|.?\n)[^"])
```